# Find all javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm converting an unknown number of vector shapes into coordinates. The coordinates of each shape are put inside it's own javascript array.

For example, the javascript might look like this:

```
var la0001 = [33,108,66,141,99,174,99,207,132,207,165,207,165,240];

var la0002 = [132,306,165,306,165,339,165,372,132,405,99,405,99,438,132,438,165,438];

var la0003 = [198,339,231,339,264,372,297,372,330,405,363,438,396,438];

var la0004 = [198,174,198,273,231,306,264,306];

var la0005 = [231,174,231,240,264,273,297,273];

var la0006 = [396,306,462,306,495,339,495,372,528,405,528,438,561,438,594,471];

var la0007 = [660,504,561,504,495,504];
```

I would like to find out how many arrays I have, in order to write a loop that goes trough each of them.

So I have two simple questions:

1. How can I find out how many arrays I have in total
2. Would it be best to wrap my arrays inside a parent element in order to make this task easier? Should I wrap my arrays inside a function or is it possible to wrap them inside a variable? Or should I put my arrays inside a parent array?

As you can see, I'm still very new to javascript! All my internet searches resulted in information on how to find the length of a single array. But how to find out the number of arrays? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`2. Yes, keeping all your arrays inside a parent array, i.e.

```
var la = [ [...], [...], [...], ...]
```

would give you the number of arrays you have by simply running `la.length`.